# jpeg opens in Photoshop 10x the filesize

Tags: photoshop

Recently when I open a file into photoshop to compress it, the file says the file size is much bigger then the actual size shown in file properties.  So after compression it is bigger than it started!

For example I have 88kb jpeg that opens in Photoshop as 1.17 MB.  Save for web brings the size to 105kb!

Are there settings etc that is causing this?  How can I have Photoshop open the file to reflect the size given in file properties?

Comment: Can it be that the DPI of the image is just far bigger? Try checking in edit > image size what the DPI is... 72 is the standard web DPI. 300 is print.

Comment: it has 72 pix/inch. Thought that might be it! but if the dpi was 300 would the file size not be bigger to reflect this?

Comment: Hmm, in that case i'm not sure. There must be some pixel conversion happening to make it sound logic. Or perhaps colour?

Comment: DPI has nothing to do with file size

Comment: but the same size pixel with higher dpi should have bigger size?

Comment: @Jon I made an edit in my answer below about resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the 1.17Mb info is not the uncompressed data size (what dimensions is you jpeg)? 
For the 105Kb output you have settings (compression level, progressive etc..) you can adjust. You may also want to strip IPTC and XMP data if any

Edit about resolution :
The resolution info (DPI dot per pixel or any other unit) is an indication on the print size. It only says how much pixel of the image it will take to make a printable inch. It s only an information stored in the image header (2 in fact horizontal and vertical resolutions). 
The misunderstandaing about resolution is caused by PS using this info for resize operation.

Comment: Ive no idea if PS is using the uncompressed data - sounds good. But why would it open a compressed file as uncompressed?  How do I check?  How do I stop it uncompressing?

Comment: I don't know exactly where you get this 1.17Mb info. What PS is showing is "no more" than an array of pixels. Obviously jpeg is uncompressed to have this array. What is your image file dimensions? Simply compute width*height*bits_per_pixel and see if you get your 1.17Mb. If so don't let this info bother you and focus on the correct export settings

Comment: its 1024x400 @ 72 dpi.  At btm left beside the 100% zoom, it says doc 1.71MB  This is in RGB mode. For example if I change to Indexed it comes up at 400kb, but I cant replicate the 88kb that properties is showing

Comment: forget about this 1.17M thingy it is only uncompressed data in your canvas.As i sayed in the other answer 1024*400*3=1228800 ~= 1.17Mb . Export for web, reduce the quality and you'll get close to the 88kb

Comment: So you are saying my file is already compressed, so when I try to compress it, Im repeating what has already happened.  So I need to compress more to get smaller files. Think I got you.  Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. But don't forget that recompressing compressed data using destructive compression will generate artifacts that can even lower the compression rates.

Comment: got it - good point.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Want to do with that?. while the image is the same no matter. checks the pixels, width and height are the same as the original.

Comment: my pixel dimentions are the same - 1024x400   Why would photoshop change the dimensions on the file?

Comment: Not changing anything, it is only uncompressed data : 1024*400*3=1228800 ~= 1.17Mb (i assume it is an RGB image )

Comment: so how can I get photoshop to open or to recreate the original compression?

Comment: should not change, but the pixels to be a compressed file can change. what you can check is whether the format is RGB image options in photoshop.